# Div width set to 100% in CSS breaks the width of my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Div Slider that swaps out Divs on click. If I change the css to the following:

```
.hslide-item {width: 100%};
```

Then the entire div width is ignored by the script. I need .hslide-item to fill its parent div 100% without breaking the JS side of things.

```js
// Add markup

$('.hslide').wrapInner('<div class="hslide-stage" />');


// Calculate Conditions & Set Vars

    // var playTimer = 9,
     slideQty = $('.hslide-item').length,
     slideWidth = $('.hslide-item').width(),
     stageWidth = $('.hslide-stage').width(),
     contWidth = $('.hslide').width();

    if ((slideQty*slideWidth) < contWidth) {
    $('.hslide-prev').addClass('hslide-prev-disabled').removeClass('hslide-prev');
    $('.hslide-next').addClass('hslide-next-disabled').removeClass('hslide-next');
    }
    else {
    $('.hslide-prev-disabled').addClass('hslide-prev').removeClass('hslide-prev-disabled');
    $('.hslide-next-disabled').addClass('hslide-next').removeClass('hslide-next-disabled');
    }

$(window).resize(function() {
    var slideQty = $('.hslide-item').length,
     slideWidth = $('.hslide-item').width(),
     stageWidth = $('.hslide-stage').width(),
     contWidth = $('.hslide').width();
    if ((slideQty*slideWidth) < contWidth) {
    $('.hslide-prev').addClass('hslide-prev-disabled').removeClass('hslide-prev');
    $('.hslide-next').addClass('hslide-next-disabled').removeClass('hslide-next');
    }
    else {
    $('.hslide-prev-disabled').addClass('hslide-prev').removeClass('hslide-prev-disabled');
    $('.hslide-next-disabled').addClass('hslide-next').removeClass('hslide-next-disabled');
    }
});

$('.hslide-next').live('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $('.hslide-stage').animate({left: -(slideWidth)}, 500, function() {
        $('.hslide-item:first').appendTo('.hslide-stage');
        $('.hslide-stage').css({left: '0px'});
  });
});

$('.hslide-prev').live('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $('.hslide-item:last').prependTo('.hslide-stage');
    $('.hslide-stage').css({left: -(slideWidth)});
    $('.hslide-stage').animate({left: '0px'}, 500, function() {
    });
});
function moveForward() {
$('.hslide-stage').animate({left: -(slideWidth)}, 500, function() {
        $('.hslide-item:first').appendTo('.hslide-stage');
        $('.hslide-stage').css({left: '0px'});
  });
}
var timer = setInterval(moveForward,playTimer);

$('.hslide, .hslide-prev, .hslide-next').hover(function(ev){
   // clearInterval(timer);
}, function(ev){
    // timer = setInterval( moveForward, playTimer);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.hslide {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    font-size:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.hslide-stage {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.hslide-item {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}

.hslide-prev, .hslide-next {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
.hslide-prev:hover, .hslide-next:hover {
    background:#ccc;
}
.hslide-prev-disabled, .hslide-next-disabled {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hslide">
    <div class="hslide-item">One</div>
    <div class="hslide-item">Two</div>
    <div class="hslide-item">Three</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="hslide-prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="hslide-next">Next</a>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time making your question meaningless for anyone that comes across it in the future. Stack Overflow has its own code snippet interface that you can place your code into so that it can run right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Add markup

$('.hslide').wrapInner('<div class="hslide-stage" />');


// Calculate Conditions & Set Vars

     var playTimer = 9,
     slideQty = $('.hslide-item').length,
     slideWidth = $('.hslide-item').width(),
     stageWidth = $('.hslide-stage').width(),
     contWidth = $('.hslide').width();

    if ((slideQty*slideWidth) < contWidth) {
    $('.hslide-prev').addClass('hslide-prev-disabled').removeClass('hslide-prev');
    $('.hslide-next').addClass('hslide-next-disabled').removeClass('hslide-next');
    }
    else {
    $('.hslide-prev-disabled').addClass('hslide-prev').removeClass('hslide-prev-disabled');
    $('.hslide-next-disabled').addClass('hslide-next').removeClass('hslide-next-disabled');
    }

$(window).resize(function() {
    var slideQty = $('.hslide-item').length,
     slideWidth = $('.hslide-item').width(),
     stageWidth = $('.hslide-stage').width(),
     contWidth = $('.hslide').width();
    if ((slideQty*slideWidth) < contWidth) {
    $('.hslide-prev').addClass('hslide-prev-disabled').removeClass('hslide-prev');
    $('.hslide-next').addClass('hslide-next-disabled').removeClass('hslide-next');
    }
    else {
    $('.hslide-prev-disabled').addClass('hslide-prev').removeClass('hslide-prev-disabled');
    $('.hslide-next-disabled').addClass('hslide-next').removeClass('hslide-next-disabled');
    }
});

$('.hslide-next').live('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $('.hslide-stage').animate({left: -(slideWidth)}, 500, function() {
        $('.hslide-item:first').appendTo('.hslide-stage');
        $('.hslide-stage').css({left: '0px'});
  });
});

$('.hslide-prev').live('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $('.hslide-item:last').prependTo('.hslide-stage');
    $('.hslide-stage').css({left: -(slideWidth)});
    $('.hslide-stage').animate({left: '0px'}, 500, function() {
    });
});
function moveForward() {
$('.hslide-stage').animate({left: -(slideWidth)}, 500, function() {
        $('.hslide-item:first').appendTo('.hslide-stage');
        $('.hslide-stage').css({left: '0px'});
  });
}
var timer = setInterval(moveForward,playTimer);

$('.hslide, .hslide-prev, .hslide-next').hover(function(ev){
   // clearInterval(timer);
}, function(ev){
    // timer = setInterval( moveForward, playTimer);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.hslide {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    font-size:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.hslide-stage {
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.hslide-item {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
}

.hslide-prev, .hslide-next {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
.hslide-prev:hover, .hslide-next:hover {
    background:#ccc;
}
.hslide-prev-disabled, .hslide-next-disabled {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hslide">
    <div class="hslide-item">One</div>
    <div class="hslide-item">Two</div>
    <div class="hslide-item">Three</div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="hslide-prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="hslide-next">Next</a>
```

`.hslide-stage` also needs `width: 100%`

Comment: Populus - Thanks, I can't believe the issue was so simple. Your solution is accepted and very appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time making your answer meaningless for anyone that comes across it in the future. Stack Overflow has its own code snippet interface that you can place your code into so that it can run right here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I posted the solution as well... It was a one liner fix

Comment: But, if the Fiddle goes away, how will I know what your one line fixed?